# Deconstructing an array within a state reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple CRUD app with reactjs and I am having a hard time figuring how to deconstruct data within a state. This is what the data in the state look like using the react chrome extension

```
State
 data:
  Array[3]
   0:
    Array[6]
   1:
    Array[3]
   2:
    Array[3]
```

So I guess the question would be how would I grab the properties inside those arrays that each contain an object?

Comment: what kind of structure is that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, your array is an array of arrays, which contain objects internally. You could convert flatten it using reduce method like

```
const newArr = data.reduce((res, arr) => {
   res.push(arr);
   return res;
}, []);
```

now you can loop over this array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Just do `this.state.data[i][j]`, to get the *i*-th element in data, and the *j*-th element within `data[i]`.